# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to create the following table on mySQL 5.6

```
CREATE TABLE customers
 (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment,
 cust_first_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 cust_last_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 cust_address VARCHAR (30),
 cust_dob DATE,
 cust_anniversary DATE,
 cust_phone1 INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
 cust_phone2 INTEGER(10),
 cust_phone3 INTEGER(10),
 cust_fax INTEGER(10),
 cust_email VARCHAR,
 cust_PW VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 cust_suburb VARCHAR(20),
 cust_postcode VARCHAR(4),
 cust_state VARCHAR (3),
 cust_gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 cust_type VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
 companies_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 employees_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 CONSTRAINT com_cust_FK FOREIGN KEY (companies_id) REFERENCES companies(id),
 CONSTRAINT emp_cust_FK FOREIGN KEY (employees_id) REFERENCES employees(id),
 CHECK (cust_gender IN('M','F')),
 CHECK (cust_type IN(‘Gold’,’Silver’,’Bronze’)
 );
```

And I get the following error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' cust_Password VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, cust_suburb VARCHAR(20), cust_postcod' at line 13`

How can i overcome this?

Comment: You have no column called `cust_Password` - and don't use smart quotes, not even as a joke.

Comment: This isn't the table causing your error

Comment: @JohnConde Actually it is (although, admittedly, not that exact error - as PravinS explains).

Comment: The column mentioned in their error is *not* in the code above. If this is the correct table then the question-asker did a poor job of asking this question.

Comment: Agreed. That's not unusual !

Answer (score 1):

mention `VARCHAR(150)` field size to `cust_email` field